# Graphic to replay state over time

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a blueprint of a house and would like to create a graphic that will show when each door was opened over the course of a single day. I do not want to aggregate the data in any way and would like to be able to replay the entire day --using a slider to control the time--and show green when the door opens and red when it closes.

I tried to use the synoptic panel plugin but did not have any luck. I was not able to get the slider to work and it would aggregate the data.

Am I using the wrong tool or should synoptic panel be able to do this?

My data have the following columns: doorNumber, doorOpenClosed, time.

Answer (score 1):

Synoptic panel is fine. You can use the [play axis dynamic slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380981?tab=Overview) to orchestrate time.

Your slider should work as well - make sure your slider works off a date/time dimension and has the appropriate relationships to filter the date. Use the [greater than or equal to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-slicer-numeric-range) option and have your synoptic chart work off of the `MIN(DateTime)`.